# Connectionn error Jupyter and Elasticsearch (Docker)

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make a connection from Jupyter Notebook to Elasticsearch both in Docker containers but connected to the same network (bridge).

Here is my code:

```py
elastic_client = Elasticsearch(hosts=["http://localhost:9200/"], http_auth=('generator', 'generator'))
elastic_index='data_generator_nvdi_geoloc'

df_out = pandas.read_csv(local_destination_path)
```

I get this error:

> ConnectionError: Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f7ada675710>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused))

I think it may be a problem of the containers, but both are connected to the same network and I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Could you please add your docker-compose.yml so we can atleast see what we are working with? :)

Comment: services:
  
  supeset:
    container_name: superset
    build: .
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - 8000:8088
  
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:7.17.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=admin
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue in your case is using **localhost:9200** as connection string. Because ES is not "localhost" inside your Jupiter container. Eeach container gets its own localhost reference. You need to adjust the connection string to your Docker's DNS record so service/container name you set up inside your docker-compose.yml file. Based on your comment you should use  **elasticsearch:9200** for your connection string.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, so what exactly should I do, I am new to this world and a bit lost. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: In your application wherever you are creating lastic_client = Elasticsearch(hosts=["http://localhost:9200/"], connection, swap out localhost for elasticsearch and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. You are a genius!

Comment: @DomingoRodríguezLópez since the answer worked for you you should click on the tick below the upvote/downvote buttons to "accept" this answer.

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js/issues/1340

Answer (score 0):

I found the working ip address like this:

```
docker inspect image-name
# look for:
 "NetworkSettings": 
    { "Networks": 
        { "IPAddress": IP-THAT-WORKED-WAS-HERE
```

Unfortunately, this address changes.

Typing "elasticsearch:9200" did not work for me.