# Reaching elasticsearch from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, docker, elasticsearch, jupyter-notebook, localhost

I am running `elasticsearch` from `docker-compose` and I want to connect `python` to it and test it. The docker-compose has the following form:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
 
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
    links: 
      - kibana
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    container_name: logstash
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
      - "9600:9600"
    expose: 
      - "5044"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    container_name: kibana
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elk

  app:
    container_name: app
    build : ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/ # make node_module empty in container
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    networks:
      - elk

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - app:app
    depends_on: 
      - app
    networks:
      - elk

  filebeat:
    container_name: filebeat
    build: ./filebeat
    entrypoint: "filebeat -e -strict.perms=false"
    volumes:
      - ./filebeat/config/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on: 
      - app
      - nginx
      - logstash
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    links: 
      - logstash

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

I am using in jupyter-notebook this very simple code to connect to elasticsearch and test it:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch(['http://elasticsearch:9200/'])

if not es.ping():
    raise ValueError("Connection failed")
```

However, the result is `ValueError: Connection failed`. Is there a problem reaching the localhost outside the docker?

I have tried also to replace `elasticsearch` with `localhost` in `es = Elasticsearch(['http://elasticsearch:9200/'])`, but it also failed.

Comment: are you able to access it from browser or curl ?

Comment: Yes, if I hit localhost:9200 I am connected properly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. It is possible to reach localhost from inside and outside the container.

```
# docker-compose.yml - if non-containerized Notebook
ports:
 - "127.0.0.1:9200:9200" # runs on http://localhost:9200
```

But your containerized elasticsearch instance does not have that ip address inside the container, which means it cannot be reached there by services also running in containers. [`docker inspect`shows the ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78201304/3755989) but unfortunately this changes per container run-time. You have to [set it to static](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/772845/how-to-set-the-within-container-ip-of-elasticsearch)

```
# docker-compose.yml - if containerized Notebook
services:
  a-service-here:
    ...
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: desired-ip-here

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: desired-ip-here
```